# Drawing a triangle using mouse

Tags: java, swing

I'm new at graphics in java that's my first drawing program i could lines , rectangles , ovals everything using mouse listener and mouse motion listener like the painting program but i have a problem with drawing triangles i tried to use polygons but it's very complicated .i really need help to understand how to solve this problem .any help will be appreciated.that's my code it's stupid because i try a new thing every second

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.    
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
/ * *
 *
 * @author D S
 * /
public class GUI extends JPanel {
    int[] x;
    int[] y;
    Graphics2D graph;

    public GUI() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        this.addMouseListener(handler);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
    }

    public class Handler implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {@Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            / /
            To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            x[0] = e.getX();
            y[0] = e.getY();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            x[1] = e.getX();
            x[2] = e.getX();
            y[1] = e.getY();
            y[2] = e.getY();
            graph.drawPolygon(x, y, x.length);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            x[1] = e.getX();
            x[2] = e.getX();
            y[1] = e.getY();
            y[2] = e.getY();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }

    @Override

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        graph.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        graph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawPolygon(x, y, x.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wooowww.... how bout some ident.

Comment: I'd suggest using something like `Path2D` and then `AffineTransform` to scale and rotate it, but that might be a little more advanced then you are looking for...

Comment: Also, how about removing most of those blank lines?!

Comment: You are also breaking the paint chain, take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting is done in Swing

Comment: As far as I know a triangle has 3 corners not 2. And you only have 2, the press coordinate and the current drag coordinate. So unless your 3rd corner is in a higher dimension you will get a line.

Comment: I started java 2 months ago i am still stupid in this .it's really my first trial for a program like painting

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which method you use, you need to know where the points should be and either use polygon or just draw the lines. There is no magic, it's just math.

There are many ways you can create a rectangle and for all remember you have just 2 points of reference:

- (x0,y0) - which is the origin (mouse pressed event)
- (x1,y1) - the current mouse position

**The non draggable method**

Instead of dragging let the user click 3 times. There you have your 3 points which are exactly where the user want them to be.

**The Simple rectangle method**

Imagine you draw a rectangle, the base line of the rectangle where the mouse is will be the base of the triangle. Those points are `[(x0,y1), (x1,y1)]` (this is an horizontal segment from the mouse position to the vertical imaginary line going through the origin).

Now the missing point is on the other horizontal side of the imaginary rectangle drawn form the mouse to the origin. Exactly in the middle of it, that would be `((x1+x0)/2,y2)`

Those are your 3 points

**The circumference method**

Just imagine you draw a circle with center in the origin and draw a triangle (equilateral) within. This is a little more tricky but one point could be always where your mouse is (x1,y1) and the other 2 are ... more complicate.

Give it a try. Just remember `y=sin(angleInRadians)*radius` and `x=cos(angleInRadians)*radius`.
You'll have to find the angle of your current point first (same formula but you already have the points, arcos/arcsin are the inverses of cos/Sin respectively). From that point you have to add/substract 180° (pi) to find the others.

Just a little heads up, just in case `radians=degree*pi/180` or simply use `Math.toRadians(degrees)` as Dima Maligin pointed out.

Comment: @OmarKamal A little note on the "circumference method" the `angle` should be in radians not degrees(In case you didn't know). You can use `Math.toRadians(degrees)` to convert or use PI and calculate them yourself.

Comment: @DimaMaligin Thanks, I improved the explanation hoping it's now more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you actually tried to do something and failed, I wrote a quick but fully runnable program that draws a triangle to the screen:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int width = 500;
        int height = 500;
        int[] x = { (width / 2) - 50, (width / 2), (width / 2) + 50 };
        int[] y = { (height / 2) + 50, (height / 2) - 50, (height / 2) + 50 };
        Polygon p = new Polygon(x, y, 3);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Thats what a triangle looks like");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.fillPolygon(p);
            }

        };
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        f.getContentPane().add(panel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy but I hope it'll help you on your way. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I will try to understand it.

Comment: Can i ask you a question. I was able to get the points i needed in rectangles using the way i wrote in the code of course it wasn't array .i really know that my code is a stupid code but how can i get my points in polygon with mouse

Comment: @OmarKamal You actualy need only 1 point to draw a Rect, it's origin.
the other 2 arguments are the width and the height of it.

Comment: That's if i want to click a mouse and i already put my points in the code

Comment: @OmarKamal you need to think of a way to convert the 2 points from the `MouseEvent` to 3 points, I am not going to tell you how to do that only because there are a lot of way to do that. One way would be to create a Reactangle from the points and use it as bounds bor the triangle.